# QGIS - Expression calculator on 600k features = Stop responding

Tags: qgis, raster, field-calculator, remote-sensing, expression

After segmenting a raster and working on a huge layer of 600 000 features, I would like identifies the list neighbors of each entity.
I was more or less expecting something wrong from this, but, maybe you have some solutions to avoid my issues.

I want to execute this expression :

```
CASE 
    WHEN array_contains(overlay_touches(@layer,"predicted"), to_string("predicted")) = true THEN
    0
ELSE
    "Area" < 0.05
END
```

But the expression calculator stop responding and QGIS become all "white".

Even after a night, QGIS doesn't respond anymore and I have to kill the calculator.

I would like to try doing remote sensing on a big raster, to see the result.

Comment: What did you expect the " ELSE   "Area" < 0.05  "part of your expression to do ?

Comment: When "predicted" is not contained in the array, if the field "area" < 0.05 then writte the value "1" (because it is true). This is on the "1" values that I want to work after that.

Comment: This is not how it work, after the ELSE you should input the return value for feature that didn't get catch by the WHEN close, you can't add a condition here. You should either update the first WHERE close or add a second WHERE close (if you do add a second WHERE close remember that if the first evaluate to true the second wont be evaluated at all)

Comment: I have already used this expression before. WHEN array_contains(overlay_touches(@layer,"predicted"), to_string("predicted")) = true the expression will write a "0" ; if it is not contained, the expression will check if "Area" < 0.05 is true, if it is true, it will write "1" (or true). After I get this information, I'm only working with the "1" values. I didn't notice any error related to this expression.

Comment: With 600 features, it takes more or less 1 min. So I guess 600k = 16 hours. But I'm not sure if it is really doing something since QGIS stop responding. And there is no progression bar to check if it is working. Do you know if having a better CPU or more RAM would reduce the execution time of the field calculator, or is it the way QGIS is working ?